# Zsh Compinit Insecure Directories & global npm issues - MacOs Catalina

Tags: macos, zsh

I decided to move all of my work over to a new user on my macbook instead of combining my work and personal stuff under the same user.
Now I have issues with zsh complaining of insecure directories:

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_cask
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_services
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_heroku
```

Also after installing node and npm using nvm, I have an issues with global packages:

```
zsh: permission denied
```

I believe these two issues are related. (Zsh permission issues)

I don't know why all the hassle just to use a new user on Mac but does anybody know the solution please? 
Most of the information related to this issue revolves around older versions of MacOs and fixes don't seem to work with Catalina.

I have tried:

```
compaudit | xargs chmod g-w - No effect.
ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true" - No effect, although I don't think that this would resolve the actual underlying issue?
cd /usr/local/share/zsh && sudo chmod -R 755 ./site-functions - Not fixed the issue.
```

Comment: Did you use `zsh` before? You don't *have* to use `zsh` as the login shell for the new user; it's just the default.